# What are all the high-score rocket ship animations?

Tags: tetris-dx

In TetrisDX for the Gameboy Color, when a certain score is achieved, an animation plays after the Game Over screen depicting a rocket of some sort taking off. I've only seen a small rocket fly after a bird, a giant soda bottle rocket, and the Statue of Liberty.

What are all the rocket ship animations, and at what scores would they appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YdVcb1ETN0) YouTube video displays all the rocket sequences. The video description contains the scores corresponding to the different animations:

> - Toothpick Rocket - 10000-29999 points
> - Small Rocket - 30000-69999 points
> - Champagne Bottle - 70000-99999 points
> - Statue of Liberty - 100000-149999 points
> - Space Shuttle (Failure) - 150000-199999 points
> - Space Shuttle - 200000 or more points

Comment: My current high score is at 108k, with my buddy at 74k and his girlfriend at 66k... my eyes were killing after the 108k. What kind of monster can go all the way to 200k?! Thank you!